# How to check WebSphere is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: websphere-liberty

How to check if WebSphere is running 32 or 64 bit?

These are the files in the WebSphere directory:

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty$ ls

Copyright.txt  README.TXT  bin  clients  dev  lafiles  lib  templates  usr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to get it with ./server version in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/bin